# Issues converting DATETIME using SQLITE3 and Objective C

Tags: iphone, datetime, sqlite, nsdate

I have a sqlite3 Database with a DATETIME column containing values formatted like this:
`2013-01-09 04:00:00`

I'm trying to figure out how to determine if times are AM or PM?

Here's how I read and convert the DATETIME objects from my Sqlite3 DB using Objective-C:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
char *DateTimeColumn = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13);
NSDate *myDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:[NSString stringWithUTF8String:DateTimeColumn]];
```

This works really well except it doesn't figure out whether this is 4:00AM or 4:00PM. 
I saw a posting suggesting adding an `a` at the end of the formatter string like so:
`"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a"` 
... to figure out AM/PM - but that caused crashes. (I of course also added `AM` and `PM` to the actual values in my DATETIME column like so:
`2013-01-09 04:00:00 AM`

but its still crashed.

Not sure if I'm doing something wrong - or if this just can't be done.

Is the only solution to have the entries in the DB itself all be in the 24hr. format (meaning: 4:00PM should be entered as 16:00) - and then use `IF` statements to subtract 12 from values > 12 so as to determine a time's AM or PM'ness?
I would have thought there'd be some automated function for this... Any ideas?

=================================

EDIT/UPDATE: 
I'm suddenly getting a '(null)' after converting the string into an NSDate. Here's the current version of the code:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss"];
char *DateTimeColumn = (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 13);
NSString *DateTimeString = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:DateTimeColumn];
NSLog(@"DateTimeString = %@", DateTimeString);
   // This NSLog gives me a good string: "DateTimeString = 2013-01-09 16:00:00"
// But when I create an NSDate object from this string:
NSDate *myDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:DateTimeString];
// ... and log it out: 
NSLog(@"the REAL DATETIME object = %@", [myDate description]);
// the console shows: "the REAL DATETIME object = (null)"
// and when I add this NSDate object to my Array of NSDates, I crash:
[tempNSDateObjectsArray addObject:myDate];

Console shows: 
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException',     
reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'
*** First throw call stack:
```

Comment: Well, what crashed? This should not crash, at most return `nil`. Presumably you have other errors in your code as well.

Comment: Yeah, I was just NSLogging some stuff out - for some reason I'm suddenly getting a NULL object on this. After creating my NSDate object, I add it to an array and I get this:  `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'`   I'll edit the question up top for more details...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`HH`, not `hh`, is for the 24-hour date format:

```
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
```

Parsing "2013-01-09 16:00:00" with `hh` as hour-format fails and therefore returns `nil`.

Note that `NSDateFormatter` interprets the date string according to the local timezone, unless you set an explicit time zone. You might want to add the time zone information to the strings, or use different format (e.g. UNIX time, seconds since 1.1.1970) to store the date.

---

**ADDED:** The SQLite `datetime()` function returns a string "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS" which is the date and time in UTC/GMT. To convert such a string to a `NSDate`, use a `NSDateFormatter` and set the time zone to GMT:

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];

NSString *dateTimeString = @"2013-01-09 16:00:00";
NSLog(@"DateTimeString = %@", dateTimeString);

NSDate *myDate =[dateFormat dateFromString:dateTimeString];
NSLog(@"myDate:          %@", myDate);
```

*Output:*

```
dateTimeString = 2013-01-09 16:00:00
myDate:        = 2013-01-09 16:00:00 +0000
```

To *present a date to the user*, convert `NSDate` to `NSString`, using `stringFromDate`, but do not set a time zone (so that the local time zone is used):

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat2 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormat2 setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];

NSString *localDateString = [dateFormat2 stringFromDate:myDate];
NSLog(@"localDateString: %@", localDateString);
```

*Output:*

```
localDateString: 2013-01-09 17:00:00
```

The time is now shown as `17:00:00`, because my local time zone is "GMT+01".

Comment: You're right - that fixed my crash :-) But now I'm getting weird hours - it seems to have added 6hrs. to all my times. Obviously we're dealing with Time-Zones here. So how do you fix **that**? :-)

Comment: @sirab333: Note also that the NSLog() of `NSDate` always shows the date in GMT, not in your timezone.

Comment: ok, good to know. Wait, are you saying that if I took the same NSDate object and NSLog'd it out and also displayed it in a label at the same time - I'd get different outputs?

Comment: @sirab333. No. `NSDate` is a point in time without any timezone information. Printing `[myDate description]` is *only useful for debugging*, because it always displays the date in GMT. To present a date to the user, you *must use* `-[NSDateFormatter stringFromDate:]` ´ to convert the date to a string.

Comment: understood. Any example on how to take an NSDate and convert its format to the various timezones?

Comment: Cool - looks interesting - thank you. I'll try out your code in a bit - I gotta run right now. But I'll give you credit for correct answer anyway, and will reach out to you again if things don't work out, cool?

Answer (score 0):

The 24-hour format is the *only* format valid in SQLite date fields.

Please note that the strings in the database are not intended to be directly displayed to the user; modifying them for the user's time zone and formatting preferences is the application's job.