# Convert SQL date to NSDate depending user settings

Tags: sql, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I need to convert a SQL date (coming from an SQLite request) into an NSDate.

I have a category for that:

```
- (NSDate*)dateWithSQLString
{  
  if (sqlDateFormatter == nil) 
  {    
    [NSDateFormatter setDefaultFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
    sqlDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [sqlDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
    [sqlDateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneForSecondsFromGMT:0]];
  }
  return [sqlDateFormatter dateFromString:self];
}
```

This works well if the user settings is 24H, but it didn't work with a setting AM/PM on the iPhone.

Simple test with user setting to AM/PM (other international settings to French):

```
  FMResultSet *dbRows = [self.database executeQuery:@"SELECT pulled_at FROM countries WHERE id = '1'"];
  [dbRows next];
  NSString *pulled_at = [dbRows stringForColumn:@"pulled_at"];
  NSLog(@"SQL String : %@", pulled_at);
  NSDate *sqlDate = [pulled_at dateWithSQLString];
  NSLog(@"SQL Date : %@", sqlDate);
```

> [2906:907] SQL String : 2012-01-01 00:00:00
>
> [2906:907] SQL Date : (null)

Same test is OK for iPhone set to 24H.

Any idea to fix this behavior ?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305482/issues-converting-datetime-using-sqlite3-and-objective-c

Comment: have you tried getting the current locale and setting it on your dateformatter object?

Comment: I have the exact same problem if I add the current locale.

Comment: It seems to work with [NSLocale systemLocale]. Is it the good way ?

Comment: @Rachel: thanks for the link but this didn't resolve my issue. They don't talk about changing user settings and consequences.